# How many $3 \times 3$ squares are there such that the four sub-$2 \times 2$ squares have a certain sum?

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms

Given $a, b, n \in \mathbb{N}$, how many ways are there to choose numbers $s_i$, $\ a <= s_i < b$, $\ 0 \leq i < 9$, such that $ n = s_0+s_1+s_3+s_4 = s_1+s_2+s_4+s_5 = s_3+s_4+s_6+s_7 = s_4+s_5+s_7+s_8$? In other words, the four $2 \times 2$ sub-squares of a $3 \times 3$ square should all sum up to $n$.

```
----------------
| s0 | s1 | s2 |
----------------
| s3 | s4 | s5 |
----------------
| s6 | s7 | s8 |
----------------
```

There must be an algorithmic (i.e., dynamic programming) solution. Four obvious deducable constraints are $ s_0 + s_1 = s_6 + s_7 $, $ s_1 + s_2 = s_7 + s_8 $, $ s_0 + s_3 = s_2 + s_5 $, $ s_3 + s_6 = s_5 + s_8 $. Another one is $ s_0 - s_2 + s_8 - s_6 = 0 $ ($ S_0 - S_1 + S_2 - S_3 = 0 $ if you let $ S_i $ the $ 2 \times 2 $ sub-squares). I don't know where to go next.

Comment: What does the sequence $s_i$ have to do with anything? And what is $N_i$?

Comment: @Arthur: Sorry, they are the same. Bad edit